# In Disney's "The Black Hole", why do Reinhardt and Maximillian fuse together?

Tags: the-black-hole

At the dreamlike end of *The Black Hole*, Reinhardt fuses with the robot Maximillian, appearing to be trapped inside him like a gibbet. What does this mean?

Comment: Gibbet = early guillotine...

Comment: A gibbet is a body-shaped metal cage, for live gibbeting or display of bodies.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbet < it appears to be a general word for any instrument of execution (including cages, guillotines, axe blocks, etc) - something new and unexpected that I've learned

Comment: Ahhh, this was one of my favorite movies as a kid... and while it's still fun, to watch it now makes me *cringe* at the bad science! LOL

Comment: The path of man and machine merge beyond the boundaries of time and space. Comparing max to a darth lord it appears the he and the good doctor took their chosen path on the way to the force.

Comment: Wow, that is way darker than I remember, I'll have to watch it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the novelisation of the book (by Alan Dean Foster) there's no mention of the ultimate fate of Reinhardt beyond his death

> "*Reinhardt’s eyes bulged from sudden, savage decompression as he and
>   the tower were thrown off into space. From decompression of flesh,
>   from decompression of dream*"

however we do see the fate of the crew of the *Cygnus* as they merge consciousnesses to form a gestalt entity

> "*Kate was Kate; Charlie, Charlie, and Dan Holland still Dan Holland.
>   Even Vincent was there. They were themselves … and yet something
>   strange and new, a galactic sea change that produced all the above and
>   a new unified mindthing that was KateCharlieDanVincent also. Dimly
>   they/it perceived the final annihilation of a minuscule agglutination
>   of refined masses—the Palomino. It was gone, lost in an infinite
>   brightness. They/it remained, content and infinite now as the white
>   hole itself*"

It's therefore likely that the final vision in the film (of Reinhardt's eyes within Maximillian's exoskeleton) is that they've also joined their *consciousnesses* to form a single thought-based entity rather than the more literal interpretation of him using Max's outer shell as a makeshift spacesuit.

Comment: As seen at 1:35 in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFv9ZRAqG1s the depiction of "hell" in the movie was fairly traditional and Dante-esque, complete with robed figures walking around in rows on paths surrounded by fire. So while I agree Reinhardt wasn't using the shell as a makeshift spacesuit, I think the intention may have been that whatever "Devil" assigns punishments in hell, being sealed inside Max (and maybe merged on some mental level too, as you say) may have been the punishment given to Reinhardt.

Comment: It's hell for both Reinhardt AND Max. Reinhardt's hell is to be a thinking, feeling, HUMAN mind forced into an unfeeling, purely logical robotic prison for eternity. Maimillian's hell? An unfeeling, coldly logical robotic mind forced to FEEL a human's terror, pain and horror - forever.

Comment: It definitely seems like an intentional depiction of hell, like a proto-event horizon.  The scenes looks like a strange combination of 2001 sci-fi imagery with christian-esque religious imagery.

Answer (score 10):

IIRC, the end of the movie was like a trip through hell, purgatory, heaven etc.

They fused because they are both the same, they are both villains (in Hell) and to borrow a phrase from another movie, "Evil always finds its truest form."

And I want to say that Max had a copy of the doctor's brain which is another reason why they are as one in Hell.
And yes, that could be seen as the doctor's punishment to be trapped inside a gibbet in hell.

You can also see what I think is the crew of the Cygnus below Max and the doctor on the stone bridge.

The religious and metaphysical themes are confirmed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole).

Answer (score 2):

As the movie earlier mentions that Reinhardt had murdered Kate's father, and he had used the crew to create his zombie crew, I alway got the idea that he had used Kate's father to create Maximillian, and he eyes you see inside Max's face were actually those of Kate's Father, as he finally gets his revenge on Reinhardt.

Comment: Ha, so I'm not the only one. This was one of the nightmares of my childhood, the father-turned-monster who was set to chase his own child. Still, as a grown-up I prefer the metaphysical interpretation from the other answers (especially since this helps to exorcise that ghastly image from my mind).

Answer (score 2):

I just watched it last night. I think the Hellscape is actually the wreckage of the Cygnus, trapped forever somewhere near the event horizon of the black hole, and Reinhardt merges with Maximillian because the law of physics have broken down in that place. It's horrible and poetic. That he's on a "mountaintop" while the demon shards of his crew shamble below suggests he's the eternal ruler of some private corner of hell.

Meanwhile, a white hole seems to open up in the midst of all that, and an angel guides the survivors of the Palomino's crew to a new part of the galaxy. What is the angel? Kate's father? God? And how will the humans survive without supplies in what might even be an entirely separate universe? I know it's supposed to be a a "good" ending for them but I worry for their safety.

Answer (score 2):

I read that they had not planned the ending; the script ended with them going through the black hole. So the ending was a bit sketchy and put together very late. In other words, interpret it however you like. But they were going for some powerful religious or spiritual or otherworldly ending. In essence, Reinhardt finds himself floating in space, and then (somehow) has integrated himself inside Maxmillian, where he ends up ruling over some barren land of robots (reminiscent of hell), while the "heroes" are heading towards... a frickin' glass corridor guided by an angel (which is supposed to complete the heaven-hell analogy). I wouldn't think too much about it...! Weird ending, but good film.

One account of the lack of planned ending can be found [here](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-news/we-never-had-an-ending-why-disneys-black-hole-lost-star-wars-1262526/):

> As the production moved towards its final weeks of principal photography, Nelson was also struggling with Ellenshaw and his team to figure out just how the film would end. Because when the shooting script was delivered, there was no real ending. Anyone who read the last page saw, in essence, “They go through the black hole…”
>
> “That was it. They enter the black hole, end of movie,” admitted Nelson. “We never had an ending for it. I didn’t like the ending. Nobody liked the ending. We just kept shooting hoping that I would come up with an ending, or that Peter Ellenshaw would come up with an ending, or Harrison, his son. We had 125 or 130 days of shooting to think about it, so it wasn’t like we had to come up with an idea tomorrow. We filmed for quite a long time before we actually did come up with it.”
>
> “We were all anxious to know what the ending would be,” said Forster, who didn’t even know what would happen until he sat down to watch the final cut. “The ending, of course, was contrived, or created, in post production. We filmed one more day involving a very complex shot in which the camera spun; we were in a contraption that allowed the camera to rotate. It was certainly meant to affect the black hole experience.”
>
> What the audience ultimately experiences when they go through the black hole is a literal trip through heaven and hell: Reinhardt is sucked into space but manages to somehow climb into the shell of Maximilian, ending up on a rock formation atop cavernous depths, aflame with legions of hooded, lost-soul, skeleton-like figures; the Palomino crew spins out of control and emerges through a divine, glass tunnel punctuated by a graceful, floating angel. Yep.
>
> “The ending turned into something like out of Fantasia,” said Bottoms. “Yeah, they went trippy.”
>
> “Those are things that we all heard about, even as children — heaven, hell, and so forth,” posited Forster. “So it’s not Bambi. I would not be able to unfold their thinking on the subject.”

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read thiis?  Can you get some quotes?

Answer (score 1):

My impression from the end of the film was more that Reinhardt encountered Maximillian beyond the Black Hole, and put himself inside the robotic suit more for the purposes of an environmental suit. This is why we see Reinhardt's eyes through the visor of Maximillian's helmet.

Comment: I remember having this impression as well when I saw it as a kid, that he basically used Maximillian as a space suit of sorts.

Comment: Reinhardt looks tired and scared in space. Max bears down on him then, after the merge, R looks around frantically from inside the suit ...in Hell.

Comment: I think you're being too literal. It doesn't seem likely he would have the time or ability to use Max as a makeshift spacesuit

Answer (score 1):

The Dr. had asked Kate to protect him from Maximillian earlier in the movie, which I think was because he feared that it would eventually kill him. However, he wasn't afraid of the black hole which was deadly. So by merging with it, he was trapped with the object of his fear. This fate was worse than just death. His true punishment was becoming the kind of creature that he had turned his crew into... they were more robot than human. Now the Dr. is in the same kind of hell that he had trapped his crew into. This was compounded by the fact that he was trapped inside his own creation and trapped inside his greatest fear.

Comment: Is there any quotes or sources that show that the intention was to trap the Doctor in the same kind of hell his crew were trapped it?